# Combine Cassandra Snapshot with updated data

Tags: cassandra

We deleted some old data within our 3 node cassandra cluster (v3.11) some days ago which shall now be restored from a Snapshot. Is there a possibility to restore the data from the snapshot without loosing updates made since the snapshot was taken?

There are two approaches which come to my mind

A)

1. Create export via `COPY keypsace.table TO xy.csv`
2. Truncate table
3. restore table from snapshot via sstableloader
4. Reimport newer data via `COPY keypsace.table FROM xy.csv`

B)

1. Just copy sstable files of snapshot into current table directory

Is A) a feasible option? What do we need to consider so that the COPY FROM/TO commands get synchronized over all nodes?
For option B) I read that the deletion commands that happend may be executed again (tombstone rows). Can I ignore this warning if we make sure the deletion commands happened more than 10 days ago (gc_grace_seconds)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for exporting/importing data from Apache Cassandra®, there is an efficient tool -- DataStax Bulk Loader (aka DSBulk). You could refer to more documentation and examples [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/index.html). For getting consistent reads and writes, you could leverage `--datastax-java-driver.basic.request.consistency LOCAL_QUORUM` in your `unload` & `load` commands.

Comment: Thank you, that will definitely make the export and import easier for us.